# zabbix.conf redirect to another port

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, zabbix

I'm having trouble understanding how to reconfigure the initial zabbix.conf file to not hijack port 80 out of the box.

Here is the default zabbix.conf provided by the application:

```
#
# Zabbix monitoring system php web frontend
#

Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value max_execution_time 300
        php_value memory_limit 128M
        php_value post_max_size 16M
        php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
        php_value max_input_time 300
        php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
        # php_value date.timezone Europe/Riga
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/conf">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/app">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/include">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/local">
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

What I want to be able to do is configure my zabbix similar to how I've done other apps on my server something like this.  There are actually already 2 apps on this server.  jira which is a Reverse Proxy on port 8080 and confluence which is a Reverse Proxy on port 8090.  I want to have zabbix on a Reverse Proxy on another port, say 8070.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName zabbix.domain.com
  ServerAlias zabbix

  Redirect / https://zabbix.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName zabbix.domain.com
  ServerAlias zabbix

  Include ssl/default/ssl.cfg

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8070/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8070/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is this doesn't work because Zabbix runs on the assumption that nothing else is using port 80.

Doing something like this just gives a page not displayed

```
Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value max_execution_time 300
        php_value memory_limit 128M
        php_value post_max_size 16M
        php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
        php_value max_input_time 300
        php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
        # php_value date.timezone Europe/Riga
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/conf">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/app">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/include">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/local">
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName zabbix.domain.com
  ServerAlias zabbix

  Redirect / https://zabbix.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName zabbix.domain.com
  ServerAlias zabbix

  Include ssl/default/ssl.cfg

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was so close!  Doing this -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName zabbix.domain.com
  ServerAlias zabbix
  Alias /zabbix /usr/share/zabbix

  <Directory "/usr/share/zabbix">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_value max_execution_time 300
      php_value memory_limit 128M
      php_value post_max_size 16M
      php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
      php_value max_input_time 300
      php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
      php_value date.timezone America/Toronto
    </IfModule>
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/conf">
    Require all denied
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/app">
    Require all denied
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/include">
    Require all denied
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/usr/share/zabbix/local">
    Require all denied
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Allowed me to hit the URL of http://zabbix.domain.com/zabbix and get the site.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should change this in Apache conf. You can search for it like so:

```
grep -rE "\b80\b" /etc/apache2
```

You will get a list of places to change. That would most probably be something like `Listen 80` and `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Note that original zabbix configuration doesn't have any configuration for ports.

So after changing what you need you should restart apache and make sure it is running:

```
service apache2 restart
service apache2 status
```

**URLs**

Also note that you don't need `ServerName` in `VirtualHost`. Zabbix will only "hijack" the "zabbix" folder and only on specific port on which apache is listening. So if you changed 80 to 8081 you should see zabbix running on:

```
http://localhost:8081/zabbix/
```

And if your machine is accessible from external domain like `zabbix.domain.com` then this will work fine:

```
http://zabbix.domain.com:8081/zabbix/
```